# How to get teamDriveId when use google-drive-api?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I use [google-drive-api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) to get list of files.

I see a parameter named `teamDriveId`,I don't know where I can get the value of this parameter.

Can you get `teamDriveId` from the response of a method of this api?

Which method did you get it from?

I see team drive from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/collaborating#collaborating_with_team_drives).

> Team Drives are only available to G Suite Business and G Suite Enterprise customers.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The teamDriveID could be found at the last part of the URL of your Team Drive. it can easily be identified because of it's unique alpha-numeric combination.

See example below:

```
https://drive.google.com/corp/drive/folders/AbCDeFgH-123XXx
```

See [this post from Gsuite Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/apps/5eZhX5Qumhc/hMUefITiCAAJ).

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I am glad that it helps, I will also be glad if you'll accept my answer. Thanks.